# Python for loop with if/else and append function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

On the basis of list as below, I have to create a DataFrame with "state" and "region" columns:

Original data:

```
 Alabama[edit]
 Auburn (Auburn University)[1]
 Florence (University of North Alabama)
 Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]
 Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2]
 Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[2]
 Troy (Troy University)[2]
 Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama, Stillman College, Shelton State)[3][4]
 Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[5]
 Alaska[edit]
 Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[2]
 Arizona[edit]
 Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[6]
 Tempe (Arizona State University)
```

(Data [link](https://github.com/realpython/python-data-cleaning/blob/master/Datasets/university_towns.txt) here.)

Desired output:

```
State   Region
Alabama Auburn
Alabama Florence
Alabama Jacksonville
Alabama Livingston
Alabama Montevallo
Alabama Troy
Alabama Tuscaloosa
Alabama Tuskegee
Alaska  Fairbanks
Arizona Flagstaff
Arizona Tempe
```

code:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['State', 'RegionName'])
    with open('university_towns.txt', 'r') as UniversityList:
            content = UniversityList.readlines()
            state_row = []
            region_row = []
            for row in content:
                if '[edit]' in row:
                    state_row.append(row)
                    region_row.append('region_to_be_repeated')
                else:
                    region_row.append(row)
                    state_row.append('state_to_be_repeated')
```

How can I replace `'state_to_be_reapeted'` with the content appended in case the "if" was True?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your original dataframe and your desired result?

Comment: Please edit these into your question, as it is kinda unreadable as comment.

Answer (score 0):

if I uderstand your question and desired output correct, you could do something like this:

```
univeristylist = []
with open('university_towns.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if '[edit]' in line:
            state = row
        else:
            universitylist.append([state, row])

df = pd.DataFrame(universitylist, columns=['State', 'RegionName'])
```

If you don't want the `'[edit]'` and `'[1]'` part etc, then you could change the code to:

```
univeristylist = []
with open('university_towns.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if '[edit]' in line:
            state = row.split(' [')[0]
        else:
            universitylist.append([state, row.split(' [')[0]])

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['State', 'RegionName'])
```

Comment: You correct Brad. I didn't look hard enough at the original code given. This should make it a bit more efficient.

Comment: Correct, time for me to go to bed I guess. Not so sharp anymore ;-). I should have added a while loop `while True:` But using `for line in file:` is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example of cleaning this dataset in the tutorial [Pythonic Data Cleaning With NumPy and Pandas](https://realpython.com/python-data-cleaning-numpy-pandas/#cleaning-the-entire-dataset-using-the-applymap-function).

#### Option 1: Do String Processing in "Pure Python"

You can use a greedy for-loop over the lines of the file and load in O(n) time:

```
import pandas as pd

university_towns = []

with open('input/university_towns.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        edit_pos = line.find('[edit]')
        if edit_pos != -1:
            # Remember this `state` until the next is found
            state = line[:edit_pos]
        else:
            # Otherwise, we have a city; keep `state` as last-seen
            parens = line.find(' (')
            town = line[:parens] if parens != -1 else line
            university_towns.append((state, town))

towns_df = pd.DataFrame(university_towns,
                        columns=['State', 'RegionName'])
```

#### Option 2: Do String Processing via Pandas API

Alternatively, you can do the string processing with Pandas' `.str` accessor:

```
import re

import pandas as pd

university_towns = []

with open('input/university_towns.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        if '[edit]' in line:
            # Remember this `state` until the next is found
            state = line
        else:
            # Otherwise, we have a city; keep `state` as last-seen
            university_towns.append((state, line))

towns_df = pd.DataFrame(university_towns,
                        columns=['State', 'RegionName'])

towns_df['State'] = towns_df.State.str.replace(r'\[edit\]\n', '')
towns_df['RegionName'] = towns_df.RegionName\
    .str.strip()\
    .str.replace(r' \(.*', '')\
    .str.replace(r'\[.*', '')
```

Output:

```
>>> towns_df.head()
     State    RegionName
0  Alabama        Auburn
1  Alabama      Florence
2  Alabama  Jacksonville
3  Alabama    Livingston
4  Alabama    Montevallo
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest version I could think of:

```
import pandas as pd

lst = list()

with open('university_towns.txt', 'r', newline='\n') as infile:
    for line in infile.readlines():
        if '[edit]' in line:
            state = line.split('[')[0]
        else:
            lst.append([state, line.split(' ')[0]])

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['State', 'RegionName'])
print(df)
```

Produces on my machine (Python 3.6):

```
      State    RegionName
0   Alabama        Auburn
1   Alabama      Florence
2   Alabama  Jacksonville
3   Alabama    Livingston
4   Alabama    Montevallo
5   Alabama          Troy
6   Alabama    Tuscaloosa
7   Alabama      Tuskegee
8    Alaska     Fairbanks
9   Arizona     Flagstaff
10  Arizona         Tempe
```